# TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer.. An error System.Exception: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm getting error all of the sudden from last two days when I tried to open particular ssrs report which works fine earlier.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer

An error occurred while executing the query.
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'ExecuteOLAP':

> System.Exception: Column name or number of supplied values does not
>   match table definition. System.Exception:     at
>   OLAPExtensions.StoredProcedures.ExecuteOLAP(SqlString server,
>   SqlString database, String MDX)

### . User transaction, if any, will be rolled back.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'ExecuteOLAP':

> System.Exception: Column name or number of supplied values does not
>   match table definition. System.Exception:     at
>   OLAPExtensions.StoredProcedures.ExecuteOLAP(SqlString server,
>   SqlString database, String MDX) . User transaction, if any, will be
>   rolled back. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6549) For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.5058&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=6549&LinkId=20476

---

It says there an error with a particular data set when open dashboard and throws error but that dataset...that dataset call stored proc and no changes were made.

Comment: But were changes made to the table that the sproc calls?

Comment: Sounds like an insert to a table that isn't listing the columns. You are going to have to look at the logic of your report and figure out what it is doing. We can't do anything to help with only an error message.

Comment: Not sure what causing the error... see below store proc